# Using FFTW just to convert to frequency domain and back gives result quite different from the source

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft, fftw

In my testcase I'm using FFTW just to convert an image to the frequency domain and back to the spatial domain. But what I end up with is a result quite different from what I started with.

To get some questions out of the way:

- The reason I'm creating a FFTW plan on every invocation of `fft()` and `ifft()`, instead of caching them, is for simplicity. That shouldn't be a problem
- The reason I convert the real-valued array to a complex-valued array before passing it to fftw is for simplicity. I find this way is harder to get wrong than using the real-to-complex DFT functions.

My code (with utility functions, macros and classes included) follows. It uses libcinder (an old version of its) for vector classes and graphics, but even if you don't know libcinder, it will be self-explanatory. Excuse the code length, I've worked to get it pretty minimal but some utility things like my Array2D class take up quite some space.

*main.cpp*:

```
#include "precompiled.h"
typedef std::complex<float> Complexf;
using namespace ci;

void createConsole()
{
    AllocConsole();
    std::fstream* fs = new std::fstream("CONOUT$");
    std::cout.rdbuf(fs->rdbuf());
}

#define forxy(image) \
    for(Vec2i p(0, 0); p.x < image.w; p.x++) \
        for(p.y = 0; p.y < image.h; p.y++)
template<class T>
class ArrayDeleter
{
public:
    ArrayDeleter(T* arrayPtr)
    {
        refcountPtr = new int(0);
        (*refcountPtr)++;

        this->arrayPtr = arrayPtr;
    }

    ArrayDeleter(ArrayDeleter const& other)
    {
        arrayPtr = other.arrayPtr;
        refcountPtr = other.refcountPtr;
        (*refcountPtr)++;
    }

    ArrayDeleter const& operator=(ArrayDeleter const& other)
    {
        reduceRefcount();

        arrayPtr = other.arrayPtr;
        refcountPtr = other.refcountPtr;
        (*refcountPtr)++;

        return *this;
    }

    ~ArrayDeleter()
    {
        reduceRefcount();
    }

private:
    void reduceRefcount()
    {
        (*refcountPtr)--;
        if(*refcountPtr == 0)
        {
            delete refcountPtr;
            fftwf_free(arrayPtr);
        }
    }

    int* refcountPtr;
    T* arrayPtr;
};

template<class T>
struct Array2D
{
    T* data;
    int area;
    int w, h;
    ci::Vec2i Size() const { return ci::Vec2i(w, h); }
    ArrayDeleter<T> deleter;

    Array2D(Vec2i s) : deleter(Init(s.x, s.y)) { }
    Array2D() : deleter(Init(0, 0)) { }

    T* begin() { return data; }
    T* end() { return data+w*h; }

    T& operator()(Vec2i const& v) { return data[v.y*w+v.x]; }

private:
    T* Init(int w, int h) {
        data = (T*)fftwf_malloc(w * h * sizeof(T));
        area = w * h;
        this->w = w;
        this->h = h;
        return data;
    }
};

Array2D<Complexf> fft(Array2D<float> in)
{
    Array2D<Complexf> in_complex(in.Size());
    forxy(in)
    {
        in_complex(p) = Complexf(in(p));
    }

    Array2D<Complexf> result(in.Size());

    auto plan = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(in.h, in.w,
        (fftwf_complex*)in_complex.data, (fftwf_complex*)result.data, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
    fftwf_execute(plan);
    auto mul = 1.0f / sqrt((float)result.area);
    forxy(result)
    {
        result(p) *= mul;
    }
    return result;
}

Array2D<float> ifft(Array2D<Complexf> in)
{
    Array2D<Complexf> result(in.Size());
    auto plan = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(in.h, in.w,
        (fftwf_complex*)in.data, (fftwf_complex*)result.data, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
    fftwf_execute(plan);

    Array2D<float> out_real(in.Size());
    forxy(in)
    {
        out_real(p) = result(p).real();
    }
    auto mul = 1.0f / sqrt((float)out_real.area);
    forxy(out_real)
    {
        out_real(p) *= mul;
    }
    return out_real;
}

gl::Texture uploadTex(Array2D<float> a)
{
    gl::Texture tex(a.w, a.h);
    tex.bind();
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, a.w, a.h, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_FLOAT, a.data);
    return tex;
}

struct SApp : ci::app::AppBasic {
    gl::Texture texSource;
    gl::Texture texbackAndForthed;
    void setup()
    {
        createConsole();

        Array2D<float> source(Vec2i(400, 400));
        forxy(source) {
            float dist = p.distance(source.Size() / 2);
            if(dist < 100)
                source(p) = 1.0f;
            else
                source(p) = 0.0f;
        }
        printSum("source", source);
        texSource = uploadTex(source);
        setWindowSize(source.w, source.h);
        auto backAndForthed = backAndForth(source);
        printSum("backAndForthed", backAndForthed);
        //backAndForthed = backAndForth(loaded);
        texbackAndForthed = uploadTex(backAndForthed);
    }
    void printSum(std::string description, Array2D<float> arr) {
        float sum = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 0.0f);
        std::cout << "array '" << description << "' has sum " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    void draw()
    {
        gl::clear(Color(0, 0, 0));
        gl::draw(texSource, Rectf(0,0, getWindowWidth() / 2, getWindowHeight() /2));
        gl::draw(texbackAndForthed, Rectf(getWindowWidth() / 2, getWindowWidth() / 2, getWindowWidth(), getWindowHeight()));
    }
    Array2D<float> backAndForth(Array2D<float> in) {
        auto inFd = fft(in);
        auto inResult = ifft(inFd);
        return inResult;
    }
};

CINDER_APP_BASIC(SApp, ci::app::RendererGl)
```

*precompiled.h*:

```
#include <complex>
#include <cinder/app/AppBasic.h>
#include <cinder/gl/Texture.h>
#include <cinder/gl/gl.h>
#include <cinder/Vector.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <numeric>
```

Console output:

```
array 'source' has sum 31397
array 'backAndForthed' has sum -0.110077
```

Graphical output:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the lower-right circle is sort of darker and gradienty.

**Note:** If you uncomment the second `backAndForthed = backAndForth(loaded);` line, the result is correct (so, the result is wrong only the first time).

Comment: The memory for the buffer `result.data` is not allocated if `Init` is not called. Moreover, using the flag `FFTW_MEASURE` can modify the input buffer `in_complex.data` or `in.data`: could you try to use the flag `FFTW_ESTIMATE` instead? See http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html

Comment: @francis: Thanks. I *am* calling Init in all cases though - see what I'm passing to `deleter`'s constructor in the initializer lists. Using `FFTW_ESTIMATE` does fix the problem but I think that's a random (IOW unreliable) fix because: even if `FFTW_MEASURE` overwrites the input buffer, that's shouldn't matter - `fft()`'s input buffer is overwritten with the return value of `ifft()` at the end anyway, and `ifft`'s input buffer is a local that's thrown away after being passed to `ifft`.

Comment: You're right, `Init()` get called in all cases. Sorry for that... Nevertheless, if `FFTW_MEASURE` is used, the input array `in_complex.data` may be modified before `fftwf_execute(plan)` is called. Similarly, the same thing happens in `ifft()`: `in.data`  may be modified before calling `fftwf_execute(plan)`. Hence, `result.data` after  `fftwf_execute(plan)` is not the DFT of the `in.data` that existed before the creation of the fftw_plan. I don't know if it is the only problem here, but it seems to be a potential explaination for ifft not being the inverse of fft.

Comment: @francis: Ah ok, that makes a lot of sense. Also I just found a reference for what you said. Quote: "the planner overwrites the input array during planning unless a saved plan (see Wisdom) is available for that problem, so you should initialize your input data after creating the plan. The only exceptions to this are the FFTW_ESTIMATE and FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY flags[...]" from [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html). I worked around it by passing dummy arrays (with the right size, type, transform direction, etc) in the plan creation, then using fftw's "new-array execute functions".

Comment: @francis: So I got it to work fine even with the `FFTW_MEASURE` flag. Please post your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
auto plan = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(in.h, in.w,
    (fftwf_complex*)in_complex.data, (fftwf_complex*)result.data,
     FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
fftwf_execute(plan);
```

and there:

```
auto plan = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(in.h, in.w,
    (fftwf_complex*)in.data, (fftwf_complex*)result.data,
    FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
fftwf_execute(plan);
```

Using the flag `FFTW_MEASURE` implies that FFTW tries many DFT algorithms to choose the fastest one. The problem is that the input array `in.data` is overwritten on the way. Hence, after `fftwf_execute(plan);`, `result.data` is not the DFT of the `in.data` as it was before the creation of the plan. According to the documentation of FFTW on [planner flags](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html):

> Important: the planner overwrites the input array during planning unless a saved plan (see Wisdom) is available for that problem, so you should initialize your input data after creating the plan. The only exceptions to this are the `FFTW_ESTIMATE` and `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY` flags, as mentioned below.

**The documentation provides a solution: using the flag `FFTW_ESTIMATE` ensures that the input/output arrays are not overwritten during planning.**

In this particular case, using `FFTW_ESTIMATE` instead of `FFTW_MEASURE` is not expected to trigger a large increase of the computation time. Indeed, as many DFTs are computed during the plan creation, the creation of the fftw_plan using `FFTW_MEASURE` will be much slower than the creation using `FFTW_ESTIMATE`. Nevertheless, if many DFTs of the same size are to be performed, the plan must be created once for all using `FFTW_MEASURE` and stored. If necessary, [new-array execution functions](http://www.fftw.org/doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html#New_002darray-Execute-Functions) can be applied.

My guess is than you are already aware of r2c and c2r transforms, designed to cut storage space and computation time by almost 2.